# Using solve_ivp instead of odeint to solve initial problem value

Tags: python, scipy, ode, differential-equations

Currently, I solve the following ODE system of equations using odeint

dx/dt = (-x + u)/2.0

dy/dt = (-y + x)/5.0

initial conditions: x = 0, y = 0

However, I would like to use solve_ivp which seems to be the recommended option for this type of problems, but honestly I don't know how to adapt the code...

Here is the code I'm using with odeint:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import odeint, solve_ivp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def model(z, t, u):
    x = z[0]
    y = z[1]
    dxdt = (-x + u)/2.0
    dydt = (-y + x)/5.0
    dzdt = [dxdt, dydt]
    return dzdt

def main():
    # initial condition
    z0 = [0, 0]

    # number of time points
    n = 401

    # time points
    t = np.linspace(0, 40, n)

    # step input
    u = np.zeros(n)
    # change to 2.0 at time = 5.0
    u[51:] = 2.0

    # store solution
    x = np.empty_like(t)
    y = np.empty_like(t)
    # record initial conditions
    x[0] = z0[0]
    y[0] = z0[1]

    # solve ODE
    for i in range(1, n):
        # span for next time step
        tspan = [t[i-1], t[i]]
        # solve for next step
        z = odeint(model, z0, tspan, args=(u[i],))
        # store solution for plotting
        x[i] = z[1][0]
        y[i] = z[1][1]
        # next initial condition
        z0 = z[1]

    # plot results
    plt.plot(t,u,'g:',label='u(t)')
    plt.plot(t,x,'b-',label='x(t)')
    plt.plot(t,y,'r--',label='y(t)')
    plt.ylabel('values')
    plt.xlabel('time')
    plt.legend(loc='best')
    plt.show()

main()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's important that `solve_ivp` expects f(t, z) as right-hand side of the ODE. If you don't want to change your ode function and also want to pass your parameter `u`, I recommend to define a wrapper function:

```
def model(z, t, u):
    x = z[0]
    y = z[1]
    dxdt = (-x + u)/2.0
    dydt = (-y + x)/5.0
    dzdt = [dxdt, dydt]
    return dzdt

def odefun(t, z):
    if t < 5:
        return model(z, t, 0)
    else:
        return model(z, t, 2)
```

Now it's easy to call `solve_ivp`:

```
def main():
    # initial condition
    z0 = [0, 0]

    # number of time points
    n = 401

    # time points
    t = np.linspace(0, 40, n)

    # step input
    u = np.zeros(n)
    # change to 2.0 at time = 5.0
    u[51:] = 2.0

    res = solve_ivp(fun=odefun, t_span=[0, 40], y0=z0, t_eval=t)
    x = res.y[0, :]
    y = res.y[1, :]

    # plot results
    plt.plot(t,u,'g:',label='u(t)')
    plt.plot(t,x,'b-',label='x(t)')
    plt.plot(t,y,'r--',label='y(t)')
    plt.ylabel('values')
    plt.xlabel('time')
    plt.legend(loc='best')
    plt.show()

main()
```

Note that without passing `t_eval=t`, the solver will automatically choose the time points inside `tspan` at which the solution will be stored.